# grep two files but some words not found

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have a list of names in `fileA` and want to get those lines in `fileB.csv` that contain a name in the list.

`fileA` looks like

```
noah
liam
jacob
mason
william
```

`fileB.csv` looks like

```
noah,1
liam,2
yoyoyo,44
williams,4
william,5
```

I want to output

```
noah,1
liam,2
william,5
```

But I got

```
noah,1
liam,2
```

What I did is `(sed 's/$/,/' fileA | grep -wf fileA fileB.csv)`
or even `grep -wf fileA fileB.csv`

However, I have no idea why some words not shown up.

Comment: Can you give us specific examples of input (from `fileA`) and missing output (from `fileB.csv`)? What is that `sed` command doing there? `grep` is ignoring standard input since you gave it files to operate on.

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying the `fileA` with `sed` so that you can use this modified file as the pattern for `grep`. If so, you need to do it properly:

```
grep -wf <(sed 's/$/,/' fileA) fileB.csv
```

Otherwise, `sed ... | grep -wf fileA fileB` was just doing the `grep` command, without taking into account the `sed` part of cleaning the file.

However, there is no need to add any comma to make this work, since this alone does it:

```
$ grep -wf fileA fileB
noah,1
liam,2
william,5
```

---

Note also that adding a comma will break the matching when using `-w`:

```
$ echo "hello,bye" | grep -w "hello"
hello,bye
$ echo "hello,bye" | grep -w "hello,"
$
```

Comment: @user3362840 then there must be some problem with your file, since the ones you provide in the question work fine. Are they coming from a Windows machiine? If so, do `dos2unix` to clean the possible problems.

Comment: A DOS `fileA` would cause nothing to match. I second that those given files work just fine with `-wf` by the way.

Comment: What could be a possible reason that some words are not shown up?

Comment: @user3362840 as I said before, and Etan also, this works fine to us the way you show it. Check if your files have some weird characters (do they come from a Windows system? I asked) and also do some basic checking like "grep william fileB" to clarify.

Comment: grep william fileB works perfectly fine. I am not sure if they come from a Windows system. However, I am unable to run dos2unix fileB. It says command not found.

Comment: @user3362840 check if there are some weird characters with `cat fileB -vet`

Comment: Or if the last line lacks a newline...?

Comment: @fedorqui no, there is no weird character other than $

Comment: @user3362840 then I do not have enough information to know what can be happening here.